# Why doesn't ^ $ in .NET multiline regular expressions match CRLF 0D0A?

Tags: .net, regex, epl

I have a .NET application that makes use of the .NET Regex features to match an EPL label text string. Normally I would use the following: **^[A-Z0-9,]+"(.+)"$** and it would match every line (it captures the text in-between the epl code). However recently the EPL has changed and at the end of every EPL line there is a line feed **\x0D\x0A**.

So i changed the code pattern to **[((\r\n)|(\x0D\x0A))A-Z0-9,]+"(.+)"**
And now it only picks up the *keep out of reach of children* and doesn't recognise rest.

How can i match the text between the epl code??

This is the raw EPL i'm trying to match

N 0D0A
A230,1,0,2,1,1,N,"Keep out of the reach of children"0D0A
A133,26,0,4,1,1,N,"     FUROSEMIDE TABLETS 40 MG"0D0A
A133,51,0,4,1,1,N,"        ONE IN THE MORNING"0D0A
A133,76,0,4,1,1,N,""0D0A
A133,101,0,4,1,1,N,""0D0A
A133,126,0,4,1,1,N,""0D0A
A133,151,0,4,1,1,N,""0D0A
A133,176,0,4,1,1,N,"19/04/13              28 TABLET(S)"0D0A
A133,201,0,4,1,1,N,"ELIZABETH M SMITH"0D0A
LO133,232,550,40D0A
A133,242,0,2,1,1,N,"Any Medical Centre,Blue Road"0D0A
A133,260,0,2,1,1,N,"DN54 5TZ,Tel:01424 503901"0D0A
P1

Comment: Hi, Jim thank you for the example, but it didnt work... I used the multi-line and single line option also and that didn't work either. The closest I can get it to capture anything was with [(\x0D\x0A)A-Z0-9,]+\&quot;(.+?)\&quot; which only captured the top line 'keep out of reach of children'. If I use the ^ CARAT before the regex and the $ after  the regex string it doesn't match anything. The ODOA line feed breaks the regex match. Is there anything else i can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [RegexOptions.Multiline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) option. As in:

```
Regex myEx = new Regex("^[A-Z0-9,]+\".+?\"$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Actually, the regular expression should be:

```
"^[A-Z0-9,]+\".*\"\r?$"
```

`Multiline` looks for the newline character, `\n`. But the file contains `\r\n`. So it finds the ending quote, sees the `$`, and looks for the newline. But the file has Windows line endings (`\r\n`). My modified regex skips over that character if it's there.

If you want to eliminate those characters in your results, make a capture group:

```
"^([A-Z0-9,]+\".*\")\r?$"
```

Or, you can filter them by calling `Trim` on each result:

```
MatchCollection matches = myEx.Matches(text);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    string s = m.Value.Trim();  // removes trailing \r
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jim! I tried your suggestion a made a small tweak in my existing code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jim, I tried your suggestions and it worked...

I used the following...

```
Dim sText As String = "N 0D0A A230,1,0,2,1,1,N,"Keep out of the reach of children"0D0A A133,26,0,4,1,1,N," FUROSEMIDE TABLETS 40 MG"0D0A A133,51,0,4,1,1,N," ONE IN THE MORNING"0D0A A133,76,0,4,1,1,N,""0D0A A133,101,0,4,1,1,N,""0D0A A133,126,0,4,1,1,N,""0D0A A133,151,0,4,1,1,N,""0D0A A133,176,0,4,1,1,N,"19/04/13 28 TABLET(S)"0D0A A133,201,0,4,1,1,N,"ELIZABETH M SMITH"0D0A LO133,232,550,40D0A A133,242,0,2,1,1,N,"Any Medical Centre,Blue Road"0D0A A133,260,0,2,1,1,N,"CN54 1TZ,Tel:01424 503901"0D0A P1"
Dim sRet As String = String.Empty
Dim sTemp As String = String.Empty
Dim m As Match
Dim grp As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group

Dim sPattern As String = "^([A-Z0-9,])+\"".*\""\r?$"
Dim sPatternRegex As New Regex(sPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
Dim matches As MatchCollection = sPatternRegex.Matches(sText)

For Each m In matches
   ' removes trailing \r
   'Dim s As String = m.Value.Trim()
    sTemp += m.Value.Trim() + vbCrLf
Next

' The previous code detects where the line feeds are, replaces the old one with a standard vbCrLF, then the following code parses it like normal

sPattern = "^[A-Z0-9,]+\""(.+)\""$" 

' Standard WinPrint EPL Label: The parsed version would appear as: ^[A-Z0-9,]+\"(.+)\"$

For Each s As String In sTemp.Split(vbCrLf)
   m = Regex.Match(s.Trim, sPattern)
   grp = m.Groups(1)
   sRet += grp.Value + vbCrLf
Next

Return sRet.Trim
```